# Run 64bit installer on 32bit centos cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, centos, unix, vps, 64-bit

I Have a 64bit file from my old server, its ./install file

now i want run it in 32bit server, see below error:

```
[root@host ~]# ./installer.1
-bash: ./installer.1: cannot execute binary file
```

My server is centos

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 6):

Your 64-bit executable has 32 too many bits for your 32-bit operating system. You will need to run it on a 64-bit OS.

Bonus information: if things were reversed and this was a 32-bit binary that you were trying to run on a 64-bit OS, it could be done trivially after ensuring that `ia32-libs` or equivalent was installed.

Speaking frankly, though, this is 2016. There is no reason to still be using a 32-bit OS.